# Laravel namespacing - cannot use framework classes

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on an app at the moment, and I have created an admin area, and the classes for this live in an Admin namespace,

```
namespace Admin;
class PortfolioController extends BaseController {

}
```

However if I want to do thing like,

`View::make() or Input::get()`

I have to add

`use View;

use Input;`

to my controller definition, this I imagine will lead to missing functionality and will get quite tiresome, is there a way to use my admin namespace but not to be explicit about what classes I will be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to use them like this:

```
\View::make();
\Input::get();
```

You're telling PHP that those classes are not in your namespace.

Comment: Thanks, just stumbled on this myself

Answer (score 0):

If you use a namespace this means every class - e.g. View - is now located inside this namespace. Not only Laravel (facade) classes such as View, also Exception, DateTime, ... just every class. That's how namespaces work.

So you can use "use" or "\" to access classes outside the current namespace. "use" is a bit of extra work but there is hope: Powerful IDEs such as PHPStorm can add the use statements by thereselves! As long as the IDE manages to understand which class you are refering to it can auto-add the use statement.